# Que biblioteca uso para mandar notificações?

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um app onde pacientes deixaram ele em segundo plano ou aberto mesmo, e quando a vez do paciente chegar, a secretaria envia uma notificação dizendo que eh a vez dele. Tem alguma biblioteca específica para isso?
Sou bem iniciante em android.

Comment: É por aqui: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ e isto 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866623/getting-an-api-key-to-use-with-google-cloud-messaging

Comment: Uma opção é o Firebase, você pode dar uma conferida nesse link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você é iniciante aconselho a dar uma procurada sobre o firebase, como os outros colegas indicaram. Eu tenho feito um app recentemente e posso lhe dizer que você irá precisar criar uma conta no **firebase console**. Nesse acesso irá encontrar as informações como proceder com o arquivo de configuração a ser inserido no seu app.

No Gradle do seu app, deve adicionar a configuração do *sdk*:

no arquivo **build.gradle** da pasta raiz, configurar parecido com:

```
    buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
    }
```

já no arquivo **/build.gradle** da subpasta **/app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
      // ...
    }

    dependencies {
      // ...
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Com tudo configurado, seu app deverá se conectar ao firebase e buscar por atualizações dos registros, o código fica parecido:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```